# Do Some work before Saving and After Saving data in django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model class ' Newsletters'. in which there is a choice for send to like student, teacher etc.

I want to get all email of student or teacher whatever the user selected, then after save button is pressed, get the id of currently saved newsletter and all the emails of selected choice student or teacher and save it into another table called email logs.

all these work is done on admin panel of django.

```
class newsletter(models.Model):
    newsletter_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    content = RichTextField()
    send_to_choice = {('0', 'None'), ('1', 'Student'), ('2', 'Teacher')}
    send_to = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=send_to_choice, default='None')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

when admin select a choice then a query should be activated and show all emails for selected choice.  I know the query, but didn't' know how to implement this on django admin panel.

UPDATED:

i wrote this simple function for testing that if it executes then add my logic to it.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    if not change:
        if obj.send_to == '1':
            messages.success(request, 'MyModel was saved!.')
            obj.created_by = 'abc@gmail.com'
    if obj.send_to == '1':
            messages.success(request, 'MyModel was saved!.')
            obj.created_by = 'abc@gmail.com'
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the [ModelAdmin.save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
class NewsletterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        if not change: # newly created newsletter
            if obj.send_to == '1':
                for student in Student.objects.all():
                    EmailLog.objects.create(student=student, newsletter=obj)
            elif obj.send_to == '2':
                for teacher in Teacher.objects.all():
                    EmailLog.objects.create(teacher=teacher, newsletter=obj)
```

Comment: It's not working, after saving 500 server error arise, however i have tried to comment out the logic inside if conditions and show a success message. see the updated question.

Comment: Set the `DEBUG=True` and show the traceback for the error.